# Website animations not working properly in browsers

Tags: graphics, firefox, google-chrome

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; **Graphics**: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCle/SSE2;

Some website animations aren't working properly - they're often very jumpy - whereas they're smooth on my Windows OS on the same PC. Some sites that rely on movement animations are basically unusable E.g. [this site](https://florianmonfrini.com/).

I've tried using Chrome and Firefox and the result is the same in both browsers. I've tried reinstalling Chrome too.

It's a big problem for me because I'm a developer. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: My go-to for this kind of question is to suggest disabling hardware acceleration in the browser(s), completely restart them to have the change take effect, and then to see if the problem continues. Disabling HA won't actually break anything, but it often fixes strange stutters, crashes, or bugs. If it doesn't work, you can just enable HA and have lost nothing for the effort.

Comment: Thanks @KGIII. Somehow the problem was the reverse. 'Hardware acceleration' was already off and turning it on seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had *hardware acceleration* off in Chrome. Somehow turning it on seems to have resolved this issue.